# Twitter's Radius Search

Tags: google-maps, search, proximity, zipcode

On my website I would like to include a radius search for user profiles, similar to what Twitter is doing on their [advanced search](http://search.twitter.com/advanced) with "Near this places"

I currently have a US zip code database with lat & lon data, but the site is now expanding globally. What's the best approach to adding local proximity search all around the world? Adding a zip code table for every country? How does Twitter do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a Geocoding service. There are a number of options both free and paid for. Google offer a Geocoder as part of their maps API, though rate restrictions apply, and the data must be plotted on a Google map.

e.g. http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=[insert+address/postcode+here]&sensor=false

Another free option is opengeocoding.org. there are also a number of commercial options.

Answer (score 0):

Look into the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/webservices/index.html).

That's how I've done this sort of thing previously. It's not particularly clear to me what you want to do (i.e. what your implementation needs, what data you have, etc) but I used a combination of this and the lat/long that you get to determine distance.